# Using queries in check constraints

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

I'm trying to use check constraint with a row while I only have the private key. I don't know if there is another way to check this kind of stuff, I'm fairly new to SQL, so I'm also open to suggestions.

Here is a minimal example:

I have following tables:

```
Buildings:
building_id: int GENERATED PRIMARY KEY

Floors:
floor_id: int GENERATED PRIMARY KEY
floor_nr: int
building_id: int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Buildings (building_id)

Glasses:
glass_id: int GENERATED PRIMARY KEY
building_id: int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Buildings (building_id)

Floors_Glasses:
floor_id: int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Floors (floor_id)
glass_id: int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Glasses (building_id)
```

When I want to move a glass to the floor, I need to check if

```
(SELECT building_id FROM Floors WHERE floor_id = floor.floor_id) == glass.building_id
```

So I don't have to repeat the query above for each query I write.

Edit:

I end up using constraint triggers as following:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER "trigger name"
    AFTER UPDATE OF "column name" ON "table name"
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE "procedure name"
```

And raise exceptions as

```
raise exception 'message' using errcode = 'restrict_violation';
```

Comment: It's called *primary* key. I think you need a compound PK on `Floors` of `building_id, floor_id` then you can reference both those columns as one FK

Comment: @Charlieface I checked 3rd normal form while designing tables, it was saying `Every non-prime attribute of R is non-transitively dependent on every key of R.`. Doesn't doing it that way violates it? Floor_id is not floor number, it's generated key.

Comment: What does the concept of "Glasses" mean in your example?

Comment: Let's start here: why a linking table? Can  a `Glass` be on multiple `Floor`s anyway? If it can only be on one `Floor` then remove the `building_id` reference from `Glass` and remove the linking table

Comment: @TheImpaler It's coffee cup :D I made it up for sake of the example. You can think it as buildings has stock of coffee cups and I'm placing cups in floors.

Comment: The question is unclear to me. Please elaborate more so we can help. I tend to be on the side of @Charlieface but there's not enough info for me to decide.

Comment: @TheImpaler building has floors and glasses. Floors has glasses. When I'm assigning a glass to the floor, in associative table, I'm trying to check if floor and glass belongs to the same building. So we can say foreign key floor_id has one more level of indirection for getting building_id

Comment: Ah, then you need a composite key in `Floors` and `Glasses`. Need to go to a meeting; if no one has responded in an hour or so, I can write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always enforce this rule at the app level. However, I'm always distrusful of the apps (since they are full of bugs all the time), so I personally prefer to enforce the rules at the database level, whenever possible.

It's a bit more startup work but saves you a lot of time later on, since it prevents data corruption issues from the start.

You can do:

```
create table buildings (
  building_id int primary key not null
);

create table floors (
  building_id int not null references buildings (building_id),
  floor_id int not null,
  floor_nr int,
  primary key (building_id, floor_id)
);

create table glasses (
  building_id int not null references buildings (building_id),
  glass_id int not null,
  glass_price int,
  primary key (building_id, glass_id)
);

create table floor_glasses (
  building_id int not null,
  floor_id int not null,
  glass_id int not null,
  primary key (building_id, floor_id, glass_id),
  foreign key (building_id, floor_id) references floors (building_id, floor_id),
  foreign key (building_id, glass_id) references glasses (building_id, glass_id)
);
```

The key concept is in the last table. There's only **one** column `building_id` that is used in **two** foreign keys references. This *reference sharing* ensures the floors and glasses referenced in the last table always belong to the same building.

Answer (score 1):

If a glass truly can be on multiple floors at the same time, add `building_id` to `floors_glasses` and create compound foreign keys from that table to `floors` and `glasses` that include the `building_id` column. That will guarantee your integrity constraint.

You cannot define a check constraint that references other rows or tables, because it would become invalid as soon as you modify those other objects. For example, restoring a dump might fail.

Comment: No, it's many to one relation. Floor can have multiple glasses but not other way around.

Comment: Then use a foreign key from `glasses` to `floors` instead of a junction table. The solution is the same: include `building_id` in the foreign key constraint.

Comment: Ups. Apparently I made the example too basic. I have additional field for some information so I couldn't just use foreign keys.